# Multiple update of records in the same table

Tags: mysql, update

I have an update query e.g.:

```
UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = ?
```

I have all the relevant ids collected. I am looping over the ids and executing the update query for each one. In pseudo code:

```
for (id..ids)  {
   stmt->executeUpdate(query, nameForId(id), id);  
}
```

I was wondering is there a smarter/more efficient way to do this query update without looping? For instance, is there a way to create a big string once, like:

```
UPDATE table set a=? where id=? AND a=? where id=? ...etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

[Philᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/5555/phil%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9): Insert all of the data pairs into a temporary staging table, then run a single update. Will be lots quicker.

[Kondybas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7895/kondybas): Create table `pairs(id,name)` from collected data and then:

```
UPDATE table 
JOIN pairs ON table.id=pairs.id
SET table.name=pairs.name
```

*<sub>Wiki answer generated from comments on the question.</sub>*

Answer (score -1):

Yes - you can concatenate your id's into a comma delimited string and then issue the following command:

```
update table set a=? where id in (?,?,?,?)
```